# Как сделать вывод результатов поиска в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Я сделал поиск по элементам, но теперь мне нужно, чтобы выводились только нужные элементы(у меня это панели). Сама проблема в том, что если я просто сделаю панель невидимой, то ее место будет пустовать. Как сделать, чтобы панель не выводилась и не занимала место на экране?[image: там где пустое место находиться невидимая панель]

Comment: Все зависит, от того, как вы позиционируете ваши панели на форме. По картинке это не видно, код нужен. А чтобы не выводилась просто не надо выводить, вроде очевидно.

Comment: лучшим вариантом будет переход на wpf....так как стилизация на формах - треш. ps я б запоминал координаты, и потом с ними "игрался"

Answer (score 0):

Пошел немного необычным, на мой взгляд, путем. Я решил отодвигать все элементы за видимую зону, а нужные перемещать в видимую зону. Безусловно, существует метод лучше(я такого не знаю правда), но пока что буду использовать такой.